# Angularjs & Bootstrap ng-class issue

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L60L3gv9/9/ where when I match an item in the table, it highlights it with :

```
ng-class="{show: test==x.Country}"
```

Whereas I'm expecting something like in this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/nmcsr5x9/1/

but with the last fiddle I have to declare other variables in the scope.

Any ideas why the first fiddle is acting like that ?

Comment: Can you please tell me which variable you are talking about? as I'm seeing both 'test' in first and 'myVar' in second in the scope.

Comment: in the 2nd fiddle, I have `myVar` and `myVar2`

Comment: Ok, so both `myVar`,`myVar2` in second is in Scope and `test` in first is in scope so what exactly you wanted to know? both are same.

Comment: i'm not fighting against a javascript issue but rather a css issue that I don't get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you use `.show` class. This will display your `table-row` as block by bootstrap.

You have two options:

**1.** use another class name, like `.highlight`

**2.** add `display: table-row !important;` to `.show`

Answer (score 1):

In the former [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L60L3gv9/9/), in `<tr ng-repeat="x in names |filter:match" ng-class="{show: test==x.Country}">` class with name `show` is getting applied. The `show` has a CSS definition in bootstrap as `display: block !important;` which makes `tr` to follow `block` level element strictly. So it behaves weirdly in the first example.

Whereas in the [latter](http://jsfiddle.net/nmcsr5x9/1/) no `show` class has been made use of. Instead code: `ng-class="{ 'red-background' : x.Name==myVar2 }">` with `ng-class` having custom css class `red-background` has been used.

So it behaves good in the second example.

Comment: Do you have an idea of fixing it using the first fiddle ?